# How can I remove bitterness from custard after adding pineapple to it?

Tags: freezing, custard, budget-cooking, pineapple

I recently made custard with a huge amount of milk, custard powder and sugar. After boiling it for few minutes I added vanilla essence to it. After it was settled I added apple and pineapple. Then I placed the whole mixture in the fridge and the custard was tasting fine at that time. But after a half hour of cooling, when I tasted the mixture it was bitter. I googled about the issue and found out that milk and pineapple are not good friends, but I don't want to waste the whole thing now. Is there any way to reduce the bitterness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. This is caused by an irreversible chemical reaction. The bitterness is there to stay.

If it is just a tad too much for you, you can try diluting: make more pudding and mix it into the bitter pudding. But if it is the strong bitterness I know from mixing milk and fruit enzymes, that won't help either.

Comment: got it. thanks. Will try separating all the pineapple pieces and then diluting the mixture a bit. Hope that brings down the bitterness level.

Comment: Indeed, the reaction happens mostly at the place where the pineapple touches the milk. If your pineapple was rather dry, scooping out a generous amount of pudding from around the pieces can help. If the pineapple's juice got mixed throughout the pudding, it won't be enough. You'll have to taste and see.